# How do I call templates with same names at different directories in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates

Working with Django 1.8

I have two templates with same name,

`base.html` at `/mysite/templates/base.html`

and another from an app with the same name (base.html) at location,
`/mysite/app/templates/base.html`

my template settings,

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

view

```
def home(request):
    c = { name: 'myname', username: 'myusername'}
    return render(request, 'base.html', c)
```

This calls the 'base.html' from the project root, but how can I call the template from the `app/template` directory.

thank you for any reference!

Update:

I've added the app location to the template dirs,

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/templates')],
```

now my IDE shows both the files, still the root's `base.html` is rendered. how do I reference one template over the other?

Update:
Fixed with adding one more directory at the app template level.

now my app templates directory structure looks like this,

`mysite/app/templates/app/base.html`

`os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/templates')` is not needed in TEMPLATE DIR if the app is in the installed apps tuple.

more efficient solutions on Django 1.8 are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your current directory structure, you can't - it's done this way to allow you to override templates by apps later on in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. The convention is to use a directory structure more like:

```
app1/templates/app1/base.html
app2/templates/app2/base.html
```

And then use `app1/base.html` or `app2/base.html` to refer to the one you want.

**Edit**

To be more clear on what I mean: your project structure could look like this:

```
mysite
    - templates
        - base.html
    - manage.py (etc...)
    - app
        - models.py (etc...)
        - templates
            - app
                - base.html
```

Then you can use `base.html` to get the first one and `app/base.html` to get the other - and the relevant app templates are all packaged inside the app they refer to, but are namespaced.

Comment: there is APP_DIRS in the settings, thats the coolest way I guess, works well if template names are different.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I'm saying to use the name of the app inside the templates directory _inside_ the app... Not globally at a project level. Of course you'd always keep your templates packaged with your app!!

Answer (score 3):

It's good practice to create extra level in file structure. So put templates in `templates/<app_name>/` folder. Then you can reference them with `templates/app1/base.html` and `templates/app2/base.html`.

Comment: yes. It's called namespacing. It is a best practice used on several key django elements (urls, templates, etc.). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, though I prefer tightly packed apps, so moving them around doesn't need to move files from `templates/app/*` but just the app.

Comment: See my comment on my answer - I think you misunderstand both of us.

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding here: you should use namespacing even under the app: e.g. `<appname>/templates/<appname>/whatevertemplate.html`. The reason is how Django looks for templates under each app. To avoid clashing / wrong order in the discovery.