# Should django templates name for each app be unique?

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a django app. It has three apps in it, each with it's own template directory and index.html file. But when I call view from the second app it picks up the template file from the first app rather than the second one.
Is it a must that every template name be unique?
my projects directory:

```
├───jobs
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───static
│   └───templates
├───job_portal
├───main_app
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───static
│   └───templates
├───project_static
│   ├───css
│   ├───fonts
│   ├───images
│   └───js
└───recruiters
    ├───migrations
    ├───static
    │   ├───css
    │   ├───fonts
    │   ├───images
    │   └───js
    └───templates
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call templates with same names at different directories in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149424/how-do-i-call-templates-with-same-names-at-different-directories-in-django)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Django you can use templates with the same names for different apps. But you should add subfolders inside app's template directory like this:

```
my_app/templates/my_app/base.html
second_app/templates/second_app/base.html
```

Now in views you should include app name to the template name:

```
return render(request, 'my_app/base.html')
return render(request, 'second_app/base.html').
```

Comment: I’m currently learning Django and am wondering why I’d add the app name (inside the template folder) twice, as the template folder itself is already inside the app name’s scope?

Comment: I'm not certain but looks like all the template folders are merged so the app name scope is no longer there. Thats why `second_app/templates/second_app/base.html` would work